# Can’t Install Eth-Brownie on Windows 10: pipx fails to build cytoolz, saying that "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required"

Tags: python, brownie, windows, visual-studio, pipx

Good evening! I'm going through the Free Code Camp Solidity/Blockchain tutorial and for the life of me, I cannot get Brownie to install properly.

When I try and install through `pipx` I get the following errors:

```
PIP STDOUT
----------
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
Collecting six==1.16.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting inflection==0.5.0
  Using cached inflection-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting parsimonious==0.8.1
  Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting web3==5.24.0
  Using cached web3-5.24.0-py3-none-any.whl (487 kB)
Collecting websockets==9.1
  Using cached websockets-9.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]==0.3.2
  Using cached eth_hash-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
Collecting rlp==2.0.1
  Using cached rlp-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting eth-keyfile==0.5.1
  Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pluggy==1.0.0
  Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting black==21.9b0
  Using cached black-21.9b0-py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
Collecting varint==1.0.2
  Using cached varint-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mythx-models==1.9.1
  Using cached mythx_models-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.7
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.2.0
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.3
  Using cached click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting base58==2.1.0
  Using cached base58-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Collecting platformdirs==2.4.0
  Using cached platformdirs-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting wcwidth==0.2.5
  Using cached wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting pyyaml==5.4.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pytest-xdist==1.34.0
  Using cached pytest_xdist-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting asttokens==2.0.4
  Using cached asttokens-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting pygments-lexer-solidity==0.7.0
  Using cached pygments_lexer_solidity-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting eth-utils==1.10.0
  Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2
  Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting multiaddr==0.0.9
  Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.24.0
  Using cached hypothesis-6.24.0-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting vvm==0.1.0
  Using cached vvm-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.21
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.21-py3-none-any.whl (374 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.7
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py-solc-ast==1.2.9
  Using cached py_solc_ast-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pythx==1.6.1
  Using cached pythx-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting netaddr==0.8.0
  Using cached netaddr-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting tqdm==4.62.3
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.3
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting psutil==5.8.0
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pathspec==0.9.0
  Using cached pathspec-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.6
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting lru-dict==1.1.7
  Using cached lru_dict-1.1.7-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting toml==0.10.2
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting pygments==2.10.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting pytest==6.2.5
  Using cached pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
Collecting toolz==0.11.1
  Using cached toolz-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting dataclassy==0.11.1
  Using cached dataclassy-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting async-timeout==3.0.1
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting hexbytes==0.2.2
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting regex==2021.10.23
  Using cached regex-2021.10.23-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (273 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp==0.2.1
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting eth-abi==2.1.1
  Using cached eth_abi-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.23.2
  Using cached hypothesis-6.23.2-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting dataclassy==0.11.0
  Using cached dataclassy-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.18.1
  Using cached protobuf-3.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.16.4-py3-none-any.whl (219 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.6
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting yarl==1.6.3
  Using cached yarl-1.6.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting dataclassy==0.10.4
  Using cached dataclassy-0.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.5
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.6
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting multidict==5.1.0
  Using cached multidict-5.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting platformdirs==2.3.0
  Using cached platformdirs-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting web3==5.23.1
  Using cached web3-5.23.1-py3-none-any.whl (486 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting vyper==0.2.16
  Using cached vyper-0.2.16-py3-none-any.whl (236 kB)
Collecting wrapt==1.12.1
  Using cached wrapt-1.12.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting packaging==21.0
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting py-solc-x==1.1.0
  Using cached py_solc_x-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting iniconfig==1.1.1
  Using cached iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting hypothesis==6.21.6
  Using cached hypothesis-6.21.6-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting cytoolz==0.11.0
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.0.tar.gz (477 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting idna==3.2
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting eip712==0.1.0
  Using cached eip712-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.1
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting chardet==4.0.0
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting eth-typing==2.2.2
  Using cached eth_typing-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.18.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Collecting py==1.10.0
  Using cached py-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting pytest-forked==1.3.0
  Using cached pytest_forked-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv==0.16.0
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting eth-keys==0.3.3
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting execnet==1.9.0
  Using cached execnet-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
  Using cached lazy_object_proxy-1.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pycryptodome==3.10.1
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.10.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting sortedcontainers==2.4.0
  Using cached sortedcontainers-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting bitarray==1.2.2
  Using cached bitarray-1.2.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting semantic-version==2.8.5
  Using cached semantic_version-2.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.20-py3-none-any.whl (370 kB)
Collecting tomli==1.2.1
  Using cached tomli-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions==0.4.3
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting rlp==1.2.0
  Using cached rlp-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting regex==2021.8.28
  Using cached regex-2021.8.28-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (271 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting eth-event==1.2.3
  Using cached eth_event-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting requests==2.26.0
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\karee\.local\pipx\shared\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema==3.2.0->eth-brownie) (59.0.1)
Collecting atomicwrites>=1.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting pywin32>=223
  Using cached pywin32-302-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: cytoolz
  Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build cytoolz
Installing collected packages: toolz, eth-typing, eth-hash, cytoolz, six, pyparsing, eth-utils, varint, urllib3, toml, rlp, pyrsistent, pycryptodome, py, pluggy, parsimonious, packaging, netaddr, multidict, iniconfig, idna, hexbytes, eth-keys, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, base58, attrs, atomicwrites, yarl, typing-extensions, requests, python-dateutil, pytest, multiaddr, jsonschema, inflection, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-abi, chardet, bitarray, async-timeout, websockets, wcwidth, tomli, sortedcontainers, semantic-version, regex, pywin32, pytest-forked, pyjwt, pygments, protobuf, platformdirs, pathspec, mythx-models, mypy-extensions, lru-dict, ipfshttpclient, execnet, eth-account, dataclassy, click, asttokens, aiohttp, wrapt, web3, vyper, vvm, tqdm, pyyaml, pythx, python-dotenv, pytest-xdist, pygments-lexer-solidity, py-solc-x, py-solc-ast, psutil, prompt-toolkit, lazy-object-proxy, hypothesis, eth-event, eip712, black, eth-brownie
    Running setup.py install for cytoolz: started
    Running setup.py install for cytoolz: finished with status 'error'

PIP STDERR
----------
WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'protobuf' candidate (version 3.18.0 at https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/9f3cb458266ef5cdeaa1e72a90b9eda100e3d1803cbd7ec02f0846da83c3/protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=615099e52e9fbc9fde00177267a94ca820ecf4e80093e390753568b7d8cb3c1a (from https://pypi.org/simple/protobuf/))
Reason for being yanked: This version claims to support Python 2 but does not
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-56ye5rnx'
       cwd: C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1icshb0q\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\
  Complete output (50 lines):
  ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
  running build_ext
  building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3z8v36gn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\include\site\python3.10\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1icshb0q\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\
    Complete output (52 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\shared\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\karee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1icshb0q\\cytoolz_b302ec9711b74f94b21a1602a932dfb9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3z8v36gn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\include\site\python3.10\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I try `pip` installing, the installation works, but when I type `brownie` in the command line (i'm using VSC), the term `brownie` is not recognized.

Thing's I have already done:

1. Installed the necessary Visual Studios Build tools
   [image]

2. Used `pyenv` to run python 3.9.5 because I read on another help thread that there is an issue with cython/cytoolz and python 3.10, which is what I had installed.

I am very new to coding. Really appreciate the help! I just want to be able to use these tools so I can learn more and progress in the tutorial. Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I was able to fix this by deleting all versions of python on my computer, reinstalling 3.9.5, deleting all environmental variable PATH references to 3.10 (which I had previously installed). I also had to uninstall `pyenv'.

After doing all of that, I got a new error when trying to `pipx install eth-brownie`. Here is a link to that conversation incase someone else runs into that issue as well.

[Brownie Install ERROR! Please Help](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113635/brownie-install-error-please-help)

After about 8 hours of digging, I'm finally able to proceed with the tutorial.

In the course of trying to fix this, I tried ALOT of solutions that I found here and on other websites. Being new, I didn't really understand what I was doing, and ended up creating more issues for myself.

Good luck and happy coding!