# Getting `No Python at ...` error trying to install Brownie with pipx on Windows

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, windows, pipx

When I try and `pipx install eth-brownie` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\karee\web3_py_simple_storage> pipx install eth-brownie
No Python at 'C:\Users\karee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\karee\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2021-11-15_10.52.40_pip_errors.log

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I originally installed python 3.10 (on Windows). However, had issues so I deleted and installed 3.9.5. I deleted all PATH mentions of 3.10 in my environmental variables.

I'm new to coding and don't really understand PATHs well. Any help resolving this issue so I  can `pipx install eth-brownie` would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I found a fix.

https://githubmemory.com/repo/pypa/pipx/issues/592

Basically, After installing/reinstall python, `pipx` got confused. I had already tried uninstalling/reinstalling `pipx` but it did not help.

The link above saved the day. In addition to uninstalling/reinstalling `pipx`, I deleted the contents of the `.local` file and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.local` did not work for me.

However after removing `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\pipx`

It worked!